# text-align:justify not working

Tags: html, css, text-align, justify

I've been successfully using the method described [here (link to article)](http://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/) for the past few days.

It shows how to avoid calculating percentage-based margins for blocks in a grid by applying text-align:justify to the parent container.

An :after psuedo element makes sure there is always "text" being forced onto the next line to make sure it justifies.

But in [this particular instance (link to jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/simbasounds/s6ge8uv1/) the blocks are not responding to text-align: justify.
The code below has been working fine elsewhere so there's something I'm missing.

HTML

```
<div class="container"><div class="contents"></div><div class="contents"></div><div class="contents"></div><div class="contents"></div><div class="contents"></div></div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
     font-size: 0.1px;
     text-align:justify;
}

.container:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.contents {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you make a jsFiddle of the articles only. and I get an error in the console:  "".sidebar-primary" element not found, please check Sticky Element plugin settings" justified-grid-test:92

Comment: jsFiddle in this case isn't very useful because I'm pretty sure it's related to other styles in the theme. It would mean dumping huge amounts of HTML and CSS into jsFiddle to cover all possibilities. Re. the Sticky Element error: I've turned off the plugin which generates that. (edit: I'm working on a jsFiddle now in any case)

Comment: Include sufficient code, including some HTML elements, needed to reproduce the issue. As asked, the question becomes incomprehensible as soon as the external page linked to is changed or removed.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela: Agreed. Done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`text-align:justify` works by stretching the spaces between the words, as delimited by space characters. So, in order for the gaps between the inline-blocks to stretch, there must be space characters between them. In your example case, the blocks have no spaces between them.

Add the spaces, and the blocks will justify.

Comment: I didn't add space characters when using the same technique here: http://exposureagency.wpengine.com/

Comment: Well, somebody did, because they are there.

Comment: I think this must be the right direction then Alohci. The working site uses a template I coded in php. I don't recall using spaces, and I'm having a hard time picking them up now. So you are saying there's a space before or after the <article></article> tags? edit: I see them in source now.

In any case on the not-working site, depending, it may be a little trickier inserting them seeing as it's a plugin. Do you think an :after element with content: " " would work in theory? I tried that and it's not working now, but maybe..?

Comment: Unfortunately an `:after` pseudo-element won't work because it will be inside the inline-block, and the space needs to be between the inline-blocks.

Comment: I guess I'll have to hack the plugin then. Thanks for your help Alohci. You've saved me a lot of time figuring out the missing spaces issue.

Comment: Yes, it's the space thing that annoys me for a couple hours...Thanks for the hint!